# How can I select and copy text vertically in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

This is called Column Mode Editing in Notepad++. It works like this:https://notepad-plus-plus.org/assets/images/tips/columnMode.gif I have tried Alt+Shift+Mouse Switch in chrome and it didn't work on google chrome.How can I select and copy text vertically in Chrome browser?

Comment: Unless a plugin enables this function, you can't.

Comment: Is there any plugin or extension for this purpose?